# XPath address not detailed enough

Tags: html, xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets

I am working on a simple project (more an exercise in web development than anything) and I have run into an issue pretty early on. For context, I am trying to pull in the names of the top thirty best selling products from Amazon for several different categories. Rather than a conventional web-scraper, I am using google sheets' formula `=importXML()`. This formula accepts a website and an XPath location.

Here is an example webpage: https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Beauty/zgbs/beauty/ref=zg_bs_nav_0

I ran through the inspector and found that it is a large ordered list of items after more digging I thought I found the title of the product and right clicked>Copy>Copy XPath.

This was the copied XPath: `//*[@id="zg-ordered-list"]/li[1]/span/div/span/a/div`

I entered this into the google sheet and it returned #N/A and this is no wonder because when I went into the Chome console and input: `$x('//*[@id="zg-ordered-list"]/li[1]/span/div/span/a/div')` I got a pretty large object.

If anyone could help me out and point me to the correct XPath location, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `string` to get the text.

```
'string(xpath)'
```

chrome console:

```
$x('string(//*[@id="zg-ordered-list"]/li[1]/span/div/span/a/div)')
```

**Output:**

```
Philips Sonicare Diamond Clean Classic Rechargeable 5 brushing modes, Electric…
```

Comment: This is still producing an #N/a in google sheets. Any idea why?